# move or copy a directory to a subdirectory of itself

Tags: shell

I have following directories:

```
├── test
│   └── third2
│       ├── sec2
│       │   ├── sec
│       │   │   └── Backup
│       │   │       └── third3
│       │   │           └── sec2
│       │   │               └── sec
│       │   │                   └── Backup
│       │   ├── sec5
│       │   ├── third
│       │   └── third3
│       │       └── sec2
│       │           ├── sec
│       │           ├── sec5
│       │           └── third
│       └── sec3
└── test.sh
```

I would like to move the directory `"test/third2"` to the subdirectory `"test/third2/sec2"`.

So that it looks like this:

```
├── test
│   └── sec2
│       ├── third2
│       │   ├── sec
│       │   │   └── Backup
│       │   │       └── third3
│       │   │           └── sec2
│       │   │               └── sec
│       │   │                   └── Backup
│       │   ├── sec5
│       │   ├── third
│       │   └── third3
│       │       └── sec2
│       │           ├── sec
│       │           ├── sec5
│       │           └── third
│       └── sec3
└── test.sh
```

If I do that, I am getting the error message:

```
mv: cannot move 'third2' to a subdirectory of itself, 'third2/sec2/third2'
```

Code of test.sh:

```
cd test/
#mkdir third2/sec3
#mkdir test3
for f in *; do
        if [ -d "$f" ]; then
        cd "$f"
        echo "cd directories $f"
                for i in *; do
                        if [ -d "$i" ]; then
                                echo "Dir $i"
                                cd -
                                mv "$f" "$f"/"$i"
                        fi

                done
        fi
done
```

How can I do that - I am new to Unix.

The parent directory of third2 should be sec2 and the parent directory of sec 2 should be test.

EDIT: with new Example.:
Thanks for your answers - I was able to change the name of single directories, but not of multiple ones. It is not doing it correctly.

I have following directories.:

```
├── songs
│   ├── Song 1
│   │   └── 1950
│   │       ├── A.txt
│   │       ├── B.txt
│   │       ├── C.txt
│   │       ├── D.txt
│   │       ├── E.txt
│   │       ├── F.txt
│   │       ├── G.txt
│   │       └── H.txt
│   ├── Song 2
│   │   ├── 1920
│   │   │   ├── A.txt
│   │   │   ├── B.txt
│   │   │   ├── C.txt
│   │   │   └── D.txt
│   │   └── 2000
│   │       ├── A.txt
│   │       └── B.txt
│   ├── Song 3
│   │   └── 2015
│   │       ├── A.txt
│   │       ├── B.txt
│   │       └── C.txt
│   ├── Song 4
│   │   └── 2013
│   │       ├── A.txt
│   │       ├── B.txt
│   │       ├── C.txt
│   │       └── D.txt
│   ├── Song 5
│   │   ├── 2012
│   │   │   ├── A.txt
│   │   │   └── B.txt
│   │   └── 2019
│   │       ├── A.txt
│   │       └── B.txt
│   └── Song 6
│       ├── 2011
│       │   └── A.txt
│       └── 2012
│           └── A.txt
├── songs.txt
```

After executing songs.sh with following code.:

```
cd songs/


for i in *; do
        if [ -d "$i" ]; then
                #echo "i == $i"
                cd "$i"
                for k in *; do
                        if [ -d "$k" ]; then
                                echo "test"
                                mv -f  "$k" "$i"
                        fi
                done
                cd ..
        mv -f "$i" "$k"
        fi
done
cd ..
```

I am getting following as a result.:

```
── songs
│   ├── 1950
│   │   └── Song 1
│   │       ├── A.txt
│   │       ├── B.txt
│   │       ├── C.txt
│   │       ├── D.txt
│   │       ├── E.txt
│   │       ├── F.txt
│   │       ├── G.txt
│   │       └── H.txt
│   ├── 2000
│   │   └── Song 2
│   │       ├── 2000
│   │       │   ├── A.txt
│   │       │   └── B.txt
│   │       ├── A.txt
│   │       ├── B.txt
│   │       ├── C.txt
│   │       └── D.txt
│   ├── 2012
│   │   └── Song 6
│   │       ├── 2012
│   │       │   └── A.txt
│   │       └── A.txt
│   ├── 2013
│   │   └── Song 4
│   │       ├── A.txt
│   │       ├── B.txt
│   │       ├── C.txt
│   │       └── D.txt
│   ├── 2015
│   │   └── Song 3
│   │       ├── A.txt
│   │       ├── B.txt
│   │       └── C.txt
│   └── 2019
│       └── Song 5
│           ├── 2019
│           │   ├── A.txt
│           │   └── B.txt
│           ├── A.txt
│           └── B.txt
├── songs.txt
```

I would like to have.:

```
├── songs
│   ├── 1920
│   │   └── Song 2
│   │       ├── A.txt
│   │       ├── B.txt
│   │       ├── C.txt
│   │       └── D.txt
│   ├── 1950
│   │   └── Song 1
│   │       ├── A.txt
│   │       ├── B.txt
│   │       ├── C.txt
│   │       ├── D.txt
│   │       ├── E.txt
│   │       ├── F.txt
│   │       ├── G.txt
│   │       └── H.txt
│   ├── 2000
│   │   └── Song 2
│   │       ├── A.txt
│   │       └── B.txt
│   ├── 2011
│   │   └── Song 6
│   │       └── A.txt
│   ├── 2012
│   │   ├── Song 5
│   │   │   ├── A.txt
│   │   │   └── B.txt
│   │   └── Song 6
│   │       └── A.txt
│   ├── 2013
│   │   └── Song 4
│   │       ├── A.txt
│   │       ├── B.txt
│   │       ├── C.txt
│   │       └── D.txt
│   ├── 2015
│   │   └── Song 3
│   │       ├── A.txt
│   │       ├── B.txt
│   │       └── C.txt
│   └── 2019
│       └── Song 5
│           ├── A.txt
│           └── B.txt
├── songs.txt
```

Comment: oh sorry - test/third2 should be moved to test/third2/sec2

Comment: Consider `a/b/c`. If you move `b` to be a subdirectory of `c` then what will hold `c` now you have moved its parent out of the way? Same question applies (but with far more ambiguity) to `third2` and its subdirectory `sec2`

Comment: @keita063, please show what directory hierarchy you are hoping to end up with.

Comment: For your updated question, do we know that each "year subdirectory" is unique, i.e. that there is only a single `2011` directory that will end  up having a `Song 6` subdirectory in it, or may there be multiple `Song #` directories in one year?

Comment: There should be multiple Song # directories in one year.  In for instance 2012 we should have Song 5 & Song 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT2***:
After your last update, this is now a very specific case. And there's a lot of ways to solve this problem, here's a simple, very specific one:

```
#!/bin/bash
#cd songs/

for folder in */*/ ; # list all subfolders of current folder
do
    song=$(dirname "$folder") # extract song
    year=$(basename "$folder") # and year
    if [ ! -d "$year" ]; then #check if year folder exists
        mkdir "$year" #if not, create it
    fi
    mv "$folder" "$year/$song" #move and rename subfolder
    rmdir "$song" #will throw error if not empty, it's dirty but quick
done
```

**EDIT1**:
From your update, I seem to understand that you want to rename folders instead? it this case, you just need to update this section:

```
        for i in *; do
            if [ -d "$i" ]; then
                echo "dir $i"
                mv "$i" "$f"
                cd -
                mv "$f" "$i"
            fi
```

***Original***

First you can't move a directory to its subdirectory, what would then be the parent of this subdirectory?

you would need to mv sec2 to parent and then `rmdir` third2.

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *; do
    if [ -d "$f" ]; then
        cd "$f"
        echo "cd dir $f"
        for i in *; do
            if [ -d "$i" ]; then
                echo "dir $i"
                mv "$i" ".."
                cd -
                rmdir "$f"
            fi
        done
    fi
done
```

This will throw an error if `$f` is not empty.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is working with single directories, but not with nested ones. How can I do that with nested ones? - see my edit.

Comment: Well done!!! Thanks alot  - saved my day - ;)

Answer (score 3):

It seems as if you just want to change the names of a couple of directories:

```
mv test/third2/sec2 test/third2/third2
mv test/third2 test/sec2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is working with single directories, but not with nested ones. How can I do that with nested ones - see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your current state, and your desired state. You need to do:

```
mv -T test/third2 test/sec2
mv -T test/sec2/sec2 test/sec2/third2
```